# How can I create an ID in mongodb to group multiple JSON objects?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

**The way my tool work is:** Any user can look for a word, let's say "guacamole". Then the tool will fetch all data related to this word. ("guacamole") The response from the API will come in as a list of JSON objects. Each JSON being one post that contains the key word entered by the user.

So, after filtering and doing some cleaning on this response, I am storing each JSON object from that list individually in Mongo. I want each of these JSON objects to have an ID, or something that can be used to associate all of them with the original search triggered by the user. Like a **group_id** that identifies them all as part of the same group of posts.

Example:

```
#object 1
{
'post_id' : 123
'group_id': 12345
'content': "Guacamole is great"
}
#object 2
{
'post_id' : 234
'group_id': 12345
'content': "Guacamole is fantastic"
}
#object 3
{
'post_id' : 678
'group_id': 56778
'content': "This is a post stored for a different word search, so it has a different group_id"
}
#object 4
{
'post_id' : 345
'group_id': 12345
'content': "I don't like guacamole"
}
```

I'm using python and mongoengine for this tool I'm developing. I hope it's clear and I'm looking forward to any feedback, suggestions anyone can give me. Thank you!.

Comment: What do you reffer about group these objects? Are you trying to work as a relational DB? It's still a little confusing. Why you don't create a document and nest all this JSON on it?

Comment: I don't know. I'm learning by doing, and I don't have much experience developing so maybe my way is not best. So if it is one single document containing all this posts each with unique id, will I still be able to update it and avoid creating duplicates in it ?